# Swift : How to change navigation controller's height without adding a toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

How to change navigation controller's height without adding a toolbar ?
Here is an example of apple's iBooks app that I want to build.
I've a solution but isn't perfect( adding a toolbar below the nav controller but it is very ugly)

[image: ibook Nav Controller is perfect]

[image: I added a toolbar below the nav controller]

Comment: you could always subclass `UIView` to create this

Comment: If you could help with answer in swift/storyboard I'll appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want,
screenshot

[image]

[image]

You can not change navbar height,but you can put a view under it,and use autolayout and shadow to make it looks like part of navbar.Set it to the class you made

1. Write a view to act as the extendbar

   ```
   class ExtendNavView:UIView{
       override func willMoveToWindow(newWindow: UIWindow?) {
          let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
          self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0/scale)

          self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
          self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
          self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        }
    }
   ```
2. Drag a UIView and put it under the navBar,then set autolayout to make it always under the nav
   [image]
3. Change the navBar property in your viewController

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
           self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "TransparentPixel")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"Pixel"), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)

         }
     }
   ```

The two image used here(Note:**they are Translucent**)

Pixel

url= "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFwyN.png"

TransparentPixel

url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpQw4.png "

You can also look at the Apple example project,you can also find the two images there
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: What I post is using autolayout,you need to use autolayout to make your view under the extendView

Comment: It can't hold two lines meaning bar item to the level of nav title

Comment: Good solution, but it can't make navigation bar translucent, even in the example project from apple.

Comment: If you want to use this solution, you will not have translucent navigator bar.